# Spring boot maven plugin - transitive dependency not working

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

As per Spring boot maven plugin docs - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html,

it will include all "provided" scoped dependencies also.

But for me , it is not happening. When I remover "provided" scope, it works fine and dependencies are included.

Can you let me know how to solve this ?

I have installed maven in a windows box and running it using command prompt (no IDE)

Comment: It will include them in a separate directory. Which will only be used if you use Spring Boot to launch your app, if you deploy it to a container it won't use that directory (as it should as you marked the dependencies as provided).

Comment: Ya I saw that in the documnetation. But in my case, it is not there in the separate directory. I create the jar using mvn clean install -U. And start the app using java -jar

Comment: Add your pom to your question.